# How to override MUI parent component css to display: 'block' for buttons in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a modal that requires a change for our mobile breakpoint in which the buttons should display as a stack above each other. Each button should take up the width of the modal, something like the attached picture. I am trying to figure out how to override the  component to change the css.

Here's the parent component:

```
<StyledDialogFooter sx={{ padding: 0, pt: 2 }}>
            {(secondaryButtonProps || secondaryButton) && (
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary" 
                size="small"
                {...secondaryButtonProps}
                onClick={debouncedSecondaryClick}
                data-testid={noButtonTestId}
              >
                {secondaryButtonProps?.children ?? 'No'}
              </Button>
            )}
            {(primaryButtonProps || primaryButton) && (
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                size="small"
                {...primaryButtonProps}
                onClick={debouncedPrimaryClick}
                data-testid={yesButtonTestId}
              >
                {primaryButtonProps?.children ?? 'Yes'}
              </Button>
            )}
          </StyledDialogFooter>
```

Component that calls on the parent, accepts button props:

```
<Dialog
      open={open}
      loading={waitingForResponse}
      title={'Manage sharing'}
      onClose={onClose}
      paperSx={{ width: '380px !important' }}
      primaryButton
      primaryButtonProps={{
        onClick: onSave,
        variant: 'contained',
        color: 'primary',
        children: 'Save',
        disabled: saveButtonDisabled,
        sx: {
          ...(breakpoint === 'sm' && {
            width: '100%',
            display: 'block',
          }),
        },
      }}
      secondaryButton
      secondaryButtonProps={{
        onClick: onCancel,
        variant: 'contained',
        color: 'secondary',
        children: 'Cancel',
        sx: {
          ...(breakpoint === 'sm' && {
            width: '100%',
            display: 'block',
          }),
        },
      }}
    >
```

I have tried adding custom css with the sx prop, but it it still showing as the buttons side by side. Any ideas how to override this?   [image: Button image]

How it is now:
[image]

Comment: provide reproduction of problem.

Comment: check out this stackblitz for breakpoints https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kuctae?file=demo.tsx

Comment: I've got the breakpoints down, I just cant get them to stack on top of each other

Comment: if you generate minimal reproduction of problem than i can help you.

Comment: I shared a pic of how it looks now, unfortunately the code is far too big to reproduce

Comment: have you tried `display: 'block !important'

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought for this definitely involves using Grid.

However, not the baked in [MUI Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) but instead, take the time to learn the [CSS solution for grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) as it's far more robust.

I've taken advantage of both MUI breakpoints and regular CSS grid together:

```
<Dialog>
      <DialogContent>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "grid",
            gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(12, 1fr)",
            gap: 2,
          }}
        >
          <Button
            sx={{
              gridColumn: {
                xs: "span 12",
                sm: "span 12",
                md: "span 6",
                lg: "span 6",
                xl: "span 6",
              },
            }}
          >
            Button_1
          </Button>
          <Button
            sx={{
              gridColumn: {
                xs: "span 12",
                sm: "span 12",
                md: "span 6",
                lg: "span 6",
                xl: "span 6",
              },
            }}
          >
            Button_1
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
```

The MUI box is simply a div so that's why I put the Grid on the Box. This would conveniently utilize MUI breakpoints on your buttons so they span the whole width of the container on `xs` and `sm` screens. Regardless, take the time to learn more about Grid (if you haven't) - I find it to be a life saver when trying pin down layouts.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Stack:

```
<Stack
  direction={{ sm: 'column', md: 'row' }}
  spacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 4 }}
>
  <Item>Item 1</Item>
  <Item>Item 2</Item>
  <Item>Item 3</Item>
</Stack>
```

and replace evry Item with Button or any Component

Answer (score 0):

You should take a different approach to achieve the result you want using the components you have from material-ui. The button is designed in a specific way and changing the way it behaves should be your last option. You better put the buttons in a Stack component which you can change the direction based on the screen size. Here is how you can do it:

```
<Stack spacing={2} direction={{xs: 'column', sm: 'row', md: 'row'}}>
  <Button>Button 1</Button>
  <Button>Button 2</Button>
</Stack>
```